# Can't cancel javascript function execution with button using Rails UJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I've got a button (in haml below):

```
%button{ class: 'remove-fields', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } }
    Remove
```

which runs some javascript code when pressed:

```
    $('.edit-profile').on('click', '.remove-fields', function(event) {
    // my code here...
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

My code seems to execute before the "Are you sure" prompt appears, so pressing the Cancel button has no effect.

Everything I can find online refers to using buttons to submit a form (in which the data-confirm attribute works as expected), but I'm using the button to call code.  Is there a way to cancel code execution using UJS?

Answer (score 1):

You may need jQuery's [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

> Description: Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$('.edit-profile').on('click', '.remove-fields', function(event) {
  // my code here...
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that completely cancels Rail's confirmation dialog, which I want to keep.  What I want is that if I press Cancel at the dialog, then my code shouldn't run.